# OS X El Capitan auto-correction crazy

Tags: macos, email, autocorrect

Auto-correct in my email is correcting the word to something that makes no sense, before I'm even done writing it. IE I was trying to write correct but it keeps changing *corr* to *core* before I can finish writing the whole word even though I am not pausing.  I have OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn it off, go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Text (tab)  and unselect auto-correction.

If you want to do more, then on the same page you can tell it what language to auto-correct (if you don't want it for all languages you use on your Mac) or specific words (on the right you click the "+" to add specific auto-corrections.

If you want to disable auto-correction of a single word, then look at this answer already given:
[Answer already given for "Can I disable auto-correction of a single word on OS X"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104548/can-i-disable-auto-correction-of-a-single-word-on-os-x)