# Stop autocorrect from autocorrecting a word even if I re-type it after it has been autocorrected

Tags: macos, catalina, text, text-input, spellcheck

If I type 'grg' it gets autocorrected on the next time I press space to 'gtg'.

If I backspace the 'tg' and then type 'rg' to once again form the word 'grg', it still autocorrects (again) to 'gtg'.

It does that infinitely. Additionally, no suggestions are shown above/under the word as I am typing it so I cannot escape/cancel the autocorrection before it happens.

This question was actually frustrating to write, I found that the only way i could type 'grg' was by typing `'gtg'`  first (notice the space), then left-arrowing to the 't', replacing it with an 'r', and then right-arrowing to the end (after the space) and typing the next word.

Can I stop autocorrect from repeatedly correcting the same word even after I've re-typed it?

Looks like this doesn't happen with dictionary words, for example I can type "automatoc", gets auto-corrected to "automatic", and then I can backspace "ic" and type "oc" and it will leave it as-is.

Maybe this is a problem that only happens with learned spellings or so (I think I made macOS "Learn spelling" of gtg)

I don't want to learn the spelling of words like 'grg', because ordinarily these kinds of autocorrections are helpful. However, in the rare situation I am trying to purposefully write such a word, I feel like me re-writing the word should be enough of a hint for the OS to realise what I am after.

Comment: [Can I disable auto-correction of a single word on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104548/can-i-disable-auto-correction-of-a-single-word-on-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

Right click to bring this menu and select Learn Spelling.

Alternatively, you could set up a text replacement in Keyboard Preferences.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to learn the spelling of words like 'grg' which I may only use in a single situation. Having it automatically correct to 'gtg' is very useful most of the time, but it becomes annoying once the OS doesn't realise that I am trying to undo its correction.

Answer (score 2):

Short of Learn Spelling or Ignore Spelling, neither of which you seem to want in this case, the oS is not smart enough to recognize what you are trying to do

Comment: What's ignore spelling?

Comment: @ankii what does it do* ("What is ignore spelling" --> an option in a context menu, is not really useful answer)

Comment: I looked it up. Ignore spelling doesn't work actually. `grg` still corrects to `gtg` repeatedly, even if I ignore the spelling (e.g. when writing in this comment box i wrote `grg ,`, then I "ignored spelling" on the grg, then wrote it again, but it still corrected.